# how to vary the tableview height based on content

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4

I tried to vary the height of `tableview` based on content and I did that but the thing is below the `tableView` there will be a `label`. Whenever the table height increased or decreased, that `label` should be below. I tried it but that `label` is being at whatever the table height is given initially.If any oner helps me to do this would be great.

[image]

Comment: Your line is unclear ->  Whenever the table height increased or decreased, that label should be below.

Comment: Add that label as table footer view

Answer (score 1):

First remove below code if you have used in your code. We don't need it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
}
```

Next, while setting up your `UITableViewCell`, make sure one of height constraint is not set. Here is an example for title and description.

```
    /*  Setup title label  */
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0),
        titleLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 10),
        titleLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -10),
        titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])

    /*  Setup description label  */
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
        descriptionLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.leftAnchor, constant: 0),
        descriptionLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.rightAnchor, constant: 0),
        descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
```

Don’t forget to set `numberOfLines` to zero for `descriptionLabel`.
Boom, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to take a scrollview and add your tableview and a label into the contentView. Set the height of the contentView as a dynamic and set the IBOutlet to the tableView height constraint as below.

```
@IBOutlet var constTableHeight : NSLayoutConstraint!
```

after reloading the table set constTableHeight's value

```
let heightTBL : CGFloat = (tblView?.contentSize.height)!
constTableHeight?.constant = heightTBL
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad method, add

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44 //default table view cell height

And then add this in your class,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that table view cell's height increase based on the label in it than you have to implement a couple of methods like this (**Swift 4**)

1- This method tells the cell that increases your height automatically

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
```

2- Implement estimated row height whatever you want let's say 140

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 140
    }
```

3- When you place the label in the cell make sure the number of lines to "0". Add the top, leading, bottom and trailing margins to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  override func viewDidLoad()    
    { 
        Tablename.estimatedRowHeight = 100  
        Tablename.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
     }
```

and in your Tableview cell dont forget to give top,leading ,trailing and bottom margin to last ui component of your cell to make it dynamic in size.